# links in nodemailer not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemailer

Am using nodemailer to send reset password link to the user, nodemailer sends the mail but the link i set in the text is not working in the browser, it removes the route after reset, reason i don't know. And it prints cannot get the route

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetpasswordExpires: Date
})
mongoose.model("User", UserSchema )

var mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: 'my email',
                subject: 'Password Reset',
                text: 'Please click on the following link to reset your 
                       password' + 'https://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +  ' ignore if you didn't request',            

            };
```

**here is my get route for the link**

```
app.get("/reset/:token", function(req,res){
   User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now()}}, function(err, user){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired')
           return res.redirect('/forgot')
       } else {
           res.redirect('/reset' + req.params.token);
       }
   })
})
```

*The error am getting*

```
cannot GET /resetf94f496k9lfg
```

instead this is what it is meant to be. if i go to the mongo shell when mail is sent the resetPasswordtoken match

```
/reset/f94f496k9lfg
```

the reason behind removing route after reset in the browser url i dont know. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      return res.redirect('/forgot');
    }
    res.render('reset', {token: req.params.token});
  });
});
```

in the route. Your initial error is because you're missing a '/' in the redirect, but if you fixed it then that would give you an endless redirect which would crash your app.

Comment: thanks things are now working out it now redirects to the reset password page. i just changed the redirect to render :) coding @nax3t